# jQuery Roundabout: conflicts with jquery.easing.1.3.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery Roundabout plugin. I also have included jquery.easing.1.3.js for some other component.
Now when I add reference to jquery.easing.1.3.js roundabout animation effects are gone and it changes the item without rounding them in circle.

Have any one else faced this issue ?

This my code that I am using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.roundabout.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

var $descriptions = $('#carousel-descriptions').children('li'),
    $controls = $('#carousel-controls').find('span'),
    $carousel = $('#carousel')
        .roundabout({childSelector:"img", minOpacity:1, autoplay:true, autoplayDuration:5000, autoplayPauseOnHover:true })
        .on('focus', 'img', function() {
            var slideNum = $carousel.roundabout("getChildInFocus");

            $descriptions.add($controls).removeClass('current');
            $($descriptions.get(slideNum)).addClass('current');
            $($controls.get(slideNum)).addClass('current');
        });

    $controls.on('click dblclick', function() {
    var slideNum = -1,
        i = 0, len = $controls.length;

    for (; i<len; i++) {
        if (this === $controls.get(i)) {
            slideNum = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (slideNum >= 0) {
        $controls.removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $carousel.roundabout('animateToChild', slideNum);
    }
});

}(jQuery));
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML sample to check on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/hv8Lx/

Just adding the easing plugin makes the animations disappear?

Have you tried using one?

```
.roundabout({childSelector:"img", minOpacity:1, autoplay:true, autoplayDuration:5000, autoplayPauseOnHover:true, easing: 'easeOutBounce' })
```

Comment: After adding easing: 'none' it worked like it should
Thanks for your helpful hints